# clientRegistrationRepository cannot be null

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-cloud

> Keycloak OAuth 2.0 clientRegistrationRepository cannot be null.

Hello, discovered a problem, when trying to make use of OAuth 2.0 in my application. It fails after the startup. Message:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.WebFluxSecurityConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'setSecurityWebFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class
> path resource
> [com/microservices/apigateway/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]:
> Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> clientRegistrationRepository cannot be null

Cannot find any info in the net about the possible nature of this problem.

## SecurityConfig

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;


@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                    .authorizeExchange()
                    .pathMatchers("/actuator/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .authorizeExchange()
                    .anyExchange()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .oauth2Login() // to redirect to oauth2 login page.
        ;

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

## application.properties

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway
server.port=8765
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

#spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
#spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lowerCaseServiceId=true

spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myprovider.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8083/realms/MyMicroservicesRealm
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myprovider.authorization-uri=http://localhost:8083/realms/MyMicroservicesRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myprovider.token-uri=http://localhost:8083/realms/MyMicroservicesRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myprovider.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8083/realms/MyMicroservicesRealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myprovider.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8083/realms/MyMicroservicesRealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mywebclient.user-name-attribute = preferred_username



spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.provider=myprovider
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.scope=openid, profile, roles
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.client-id=gateway-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.client-secret=ajKhFIsMi3qJNlXkVTS8AFhYwhv3TUSh
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.redirect-uri="{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/keycloak"
logging.level.org.springframework.security.web=DEBUG
```

Comment: Have you found anything ? I think you are using gateway as a BFF.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by removing spring-boot-starter-web dependency

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me I had everything setup correctly however I needed to add this to my configuration file where `clientRegistrationRepository` was a parameter to a method (in Kotlin):

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var clientRegistrationRepository: ClientRegistrationRepository
```

Which I got from within a [Spring Security Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/core.html#oauth2Client-client-registration-repo) example.

In my situation, I was operating operating outside of a HttpServletRequest context but it should still be relevant to your case.